# React Redux Typescript : Argument of type 'ConnectedComponentClass'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am facing some issue when I try to connect a component class to redux store with connect method. If I remove this connect method things seem to work  fine.

Please guide me to solve this problem.

component code:

```html
const mapDispatchToProps: MapDispatchToPropsFunction<DispatchProps, {}> = (
  dispatch
) => ({
  changeDocumentState: (payload) => dispatch(changeDocumentState(payload)),
});

const mapStateToProps: MapStateToProps<ReduxProps, {}, AppState> = (
  state: AppState
): ReduxProps => ({
  user: selectCurrentUser(state),
});

// tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
export const InfoTable = withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TableComponent)
);
```

```html
/home/node/src/components/InfoTable/InfoTable.tsx
(424,3): Argument of type 'ConnectedComponentClass<typeof TableComponent, Pick<Props, "page" | "classes" | "theme" | "data" | "label" | "location" | "rows" | "dataLength" | "rowsPerPage" | "handleChangePage" | "handleChangeRowsPerPage" | "hidePagination" | "handleOpen">>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<ConsistentWith<Pick<Props, "page" | "classes" | "theme" | "data" | "label" | "location" | "rows" | "dataLength" | "rowsPerPage" | "handleChangePage" | "handleChangeRowsPerPage" | "hidePagination" | "handleOpen">, WithStyles<...>>>'.
  Type 'ConnectedComponentClass<typeof TableComponent, Pick<Props, "page" | "classes" | "theme" | "data" | "label" | "location" | "rows" | "dataLength" | "rowsPerPage" | "handleChangePage" | "handleChangeRowsPerPage" | "hidePagination" | "handleOpen">>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<ConsistentWith<Pick<Props, "page" | "classes" | "theme" | "data" | "label" | "location" | "rows" | "dataLength" | "rowsPerPage" | "handleChangePage" | "handleChangeRowsPerPage" | "hidePagination" | "handleOpen">, WithStyles<...>>, any>'.
    Types of property 'propTypes' are incompatible.
      Type 'WeakValidationMap<Pick<Props, "page" | "classes" | "theme" | "data" | "label" | "location" | "rows" | "dataLength" | "rowsPerPage" | "handleChangePage" | "handleChangeRowsPerPage" | "hidePagination" | "handleOpen">> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ValidationMap<ConsistentWith<Pick<Props, "page" | "classes" | "theme" | "data" | "label" | "location" | "rows" | "dataLength" | "rowsPerPage" | "handleChangePage" | "handleChangeRowsPerPage" | "hidePagination" | "handleOpen">, WithStyles<...>>> | undefined'.
        Type 'WeakValidationMap<Pick<Props, "page" | "classes" | "theme" | "data" | "label" | "location" | "rows" | "dataLength" | "rowsPerPage" | "handleChangePage" | "handleChangeRowsPerPage" | "hidePagination" | "handleOpen">>' is not assignable to type 'ValidationMap<ConsistentWith<Pick<Props, "page" | "classes" | "theme" | "data" | "label" | "location" | "rows" | "dataLength" | "rowsPerPage" | "handleChangePage" | "handleChangeRowsPerPage" | "hidePagination" | "handleOpen">, WithStyles<...>>>'.
          Types of property 'page' are incompatible.
            Type 'Validator<number | null | undefined> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Validator<number | undefined> | undefined'.
              Type 'Validator<number | null | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Validator<number | undefined>'.
                Type 'number | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number | undefined'.
                  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number | undefined'.
```

Comment: Could you please share code instead of image of code editor.

Comment: just added please have a look

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce a lot of the types like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps  = {changeDocumentState} // If you just pass the function, it will behave just like your code above by wrapping the functions.
const mapStateToProps(
  state: AppState
) => ({
  user: selectCurrentUser(state), // Setting the type of the state is enough
});

export const InfoTable = withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TableComponent)
);
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for replying. Still facing the same issue.

Comment: Even if I do:        export const InfoTable = withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(
  connect(null, null)(TableComponent)
);

Comment: Seems like you have a type mismatch. Can you share the types of the validator of the app state and of the component you are passing the data to.